# Find all possible solutions of $\sqrt[3]{(x^2 + x - 1)} + \sqrt[3]{(10 - x - x^2)} = 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

**The Question:** Find all possible solutions $x$ to the equation $\sqrt[3]{(x^2 + x - 1)} + \sqrt[3]{(10 - x - x^2)} = 3$.

**My answer:**

Let $x^2 + x - 1 = y$.

Then, $\sqrt[3]{y} + \sqrt[3]{9 - y} = 3.$

So, $\sqrt[3]{9 - y} = 3 - \sqrt[3]{y}$.

Cubing both sides, we get, $9 - y = 27 - 27\sqrt[3]{y} + 9(\sqrt[3]{y})^2 - y.$

Simplifying and dividing by $9$, we get $(\sqrt[3]{y})^2 - 3\sqrt[3]{y} + 2 = 0.$

Factoring, we get: $(\sqrt[3]{y} - 1)(\sqrt[3]{y} - 2) = 0.$

Therefore, we get $y = 1, \sqrt[3]{2}$.

Substituting this back into the equation $x^2 + x - 1 = y$, we get $\boxed{x = 1, -2,}$ and $\boxed{{\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{37}}{2}}}$.

Comment: Are you asking for proof verification or did you just want to post the answer for other people? If the latter it's a good idea to answer the question below (undelete/edit the answer) so that the system doesn't think the question is unsolved. If the former consider adding the proof-verification tag.[tag:proof-verification]

Comment: @kingW3 ok thanks!

Comment: The answer is correct but the work shown is incorrect.  You should have $(\sqrt[3]{y})^2 + 3\sqrt[3]{y} +2 = 0$

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales thanks for pointing that out! I think it's actually $- 3 \sqrt[3]{y}$ not plus, but thanks!

Comment: Correct, that was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, let $x^2+x=t+\frac{11}2$ to get the symmetric equation in $t$

$$\sqrt[3]{\frac92-t} + \sqrt[3]{\frac92+t} = 3 \implies 
\sqrt[3]{\left(\frac{9}2\right)^2-t^2}=2\implies t=\pm \frac72
$$

which leads to $x^2+x=9$ and $x^2+x=2$.

Comment: Thanks for another sol!